# The Others movie clarifications please

Tags: plot-explanation, the-others

So here are my questions.

1. Why was her husband so unhappy to see her when she found him in the woods but when he saw the kids he was ecstatic?
2. Why did he say he still bleeds sometimes?
3. If he was dead already, then why did he spend the day or so in bed  making it look like he had PTSD?

If anyone can help, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Very much related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/why-does-the-husband-leave-the-family-in-the-others

Answer (score 4):

1. I see two options:

   1. He does not only know that his family is dead but also how they died, which makes it difficult to talk to her.
   2. He wants to tell her that they are dead, and does not dare to do. In contrast, probably he has no plan of telling that to their sons, so he can relax while with them.
2. I took it as a metaphorical reference to his suffering and PTSD.
3. All along the movie, the ghosts continue with their own personality (the kids behave like kids, the wife still does not want strangers (Germans or others) setting foot in her house, the servants retake their role). So it is just consistent that the husband carries with him the PSTD (either from the war, from the shock of knowing he is dead or from knowing that his family is dead). Remember that one of the servants already has developed a trauma from knowing that she was dead.